# Appium 1.6 select an option from a spinner drop-down

Tags: android, spinner, appium, android-spinner

I am using appium 1.6 which does not support findByName(). When I click on a spinner it shows a dropdown. Now I need to select one of the option from this dropdown. Is there any way to do this?

This is the code for the dropdown and the options shown which are editText.

```
<com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
            android:id="@+id/warehouse_spinner__add_product"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/warehouse_spinner_prompt"
            android:prompt="@string/warehouse_spinner_prompt"
            app:met_floatingLabel="normal" />

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/product_quantity_edittext__add_product"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/quantity"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight" />
```

Answer (score 0):

here is example of code i am doing:

```
@HowToUseLocators(androidAutomation = LocatorGroupStrategy.CHAIN)
@AndroidFindBy(id = "spinnerCountry")
@AndroidFindBy(className = "android.widget.TextView")
private AndroidElement spinnerCountryText;
@AndroidFindBy(id = "spinnerCountry")
private AndroidElement spinnerCountry;
```

and code to interact:

```
public boolean setCountry(String text) {
        System.out.println("   setCountry(): - " + text);
        if (testStringsEquals(getCountry(), text))
            return true;
        if (tapElement(spinnerCountry)) {
            try {
                return tapElement(driver.findElement(MobileBy
                        .AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("
                                + "new UiSelector().text(\"" + text + "\"));")));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("   setCountry(): country NOT found in list");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("   setCountry(): country input NOT found");
        }

        return false;
    }

public String getCountry() {
    try {
        return spinnerCountryText.getText();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    } }
```

where "tapElement()" is just custom tap function you can choose any you know to tap (at least 4 ways to do this in Appium :-) )

Comment: This does not seem to be working because appium cannot find this dynamically generated edittext. When i use uiautomaterview to take a screenshot , the elements behind this drop-down are visible but the drop-down elements themselves are not visible which is why i think that appium cannot find it